# CTE get all descendants with parents

Tags: sqlite, cte, hierarchy

Schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE item (
    id        int primary key,
    parent_id int,
    FOREIGN KEY(parent_id) REFERENCES item(id)
);

INSERT INTO item
    (id, parent_id)
VALUES
    (1, NULL),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 1),
    (4, 2),
    (5, 3),
    (6, 3),
    (7, 6)
;
```

Query:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE descendants(id, parent_id) AS (
    SELECT 1, parent_id FROM item
        UNION ALL
    SELECT item.id, descendants.parent_id
    FROM item, descendants
    WHERE item.parent_id=descendants.id
)
SELECT * FROM descendants;
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/27c03/4

Goal: given some parents (eg 2, 3) get all of its descendants.

I came up with the following CTE, but it returns far too many items.

`SELECT * FROM descendants WHERE parent_id IN (2, 3);`

Should give

```
id | parent_id
4  | 2
5  | 3
6  | 3
7  | 3
```

The answer here is close, but my schema varies: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/94944/253249

Answer (score 3):

Please try and let me know if it helps :

```
WITH descendants as
(
  SELECT i.id, i.parent_id, CAST(i.id AS varchar) as Level
  FROM item i
  WHERE i.parent_id is null

  UNION ALL

  SELECT i1.id, i1.parent_id, CAST(i1.id AS varchar) || ', ' || d.Level
  FROM item i1  
  INNER JOIN descendants d ON d.id = i1.parent_id
 )
SELECT * 
From descendants
where parent_id in (2,3)
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9PUf4oPu1ohoBwu6qAGqGC/1)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914472/cte-to-get-all-children-descendants-of-a-parent)

Comment: Thanks. row id=7 is missing.

Comment: row id=7 is a child of id=6, not id=3.

Answer (score 3):

For definite base `id` use

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE 
descendants(id, parent_id, most_parent_id) AS (
  SELECT item.id, item.parent_id, item.parent_id
  FROM item 
  WHERE item.parent_id = 1      -- given base id value
  UNION ALL
  SELECT item.id, item.parent_id, descendants.most_parent_id
  FROM descendants
  JOIN item ON descendants.id = item.parent_id
)
SELECT id, parent_id 
FROM descendants
WHERE parent_id <> most_parent_id;
```

For base `id` values list (multiple trees or branches) use

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE 
base_ids (id) AS (
  SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3
),
descendants(id, parent_id, most_parent_id) AS (
  SELECT item.id, item.parent_id, item.parent_id
  FROM base_ids
  JOIN item ON base_ids.id = item.parent_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT item.id, item.parent_id, descendants.most_parent_id
  FROM descendants
  JOIN item ON descendants.id = item.parent_id
)
SELECT * 
FROM descendants
WHERE parent_id <> most_parent_id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=bda692a6854b8af9d53f337e98fd9604

Comment: Thanks. Definite base `id` is good enough. First solution does't help much, as I need a way to get row id=7 when I ask for all descendants of id=3. Second solution also isn't perfect, since I have to look for id=3 in parent_id _and_ most_parent_id. However if the results don't have any other issues then that's acceptable.

Comment: @mustafa.0x Simply remove WHERE condition if you need to see both specified `id` and its descendants.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understood, could you share a fiddle?